# How to add downloadUrl to the firebaseDB object?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have an issue with Firebase Storage and Realtime DB. My firebase object consists of 4 String fields, three of them are from EditText widgets,  the fourth must be the downloadURL of an image I put into Firebase Storage, but I can't understand how to put it there.

My current code for pushing data to FirebaseDB is below:

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                menuItem menuItem = new menuItem(name.getText().toString(), description.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(price.getText().toString()), mChosenStorageRef.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                mChosenDBRef.push().setValue(menuItem);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.price_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }

            name.setText("");
            description.setText("");
            price.setText("");
```

The `mChosenStorageRef.getDownloadUrl().toString()` method gives me something like "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzh@96b2841" but not the correct URL.

I can get the correct donwloadURL from the code below, bot I can't understand how to put it into the push method above.

```
uploadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, RC_PHOTO_PICKER);




        }
    });


}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER)
    {

        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
       mChosenStorageRef = mChosenStorageRef.child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
        mChosenStorageRef.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was more easy then I've ever expected. I stored the URI to an URI variable outside of onCreate and used it in upload method later.

Need to study java more and more. Thanks everyone for attention and help.

```
 private Uri downloadURL;
```

---

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            try {
                menuItem menuItem = new menuItem(name.getText().toString(), description.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(price.getText().toString()), downloadURL.toString());
                mChosenDBRef.push().setValue(menuItem);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.price_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
```

---

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER) {

         Uri imageUri = data.getData();


        mChosenStorageRef = mChosenStorageRef.child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
        mChosenStorageRef.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {


            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

               downloadURL = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();




            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just get `Task<Uri>` from `mChosenStorageRef.getDownloadUrl()`

I have 2 ideas to get a downloadUrl for you.

1. Save **taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()** as string to an instance variable from putFile 's callback then you might check a value of this variable before sending to RTDB if you require.

   ```
   mDownloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
   ```
2. Get downloadUrl from Storage, in this way you need a callback response first, after that you will get uri then convert it to string and send to RTDB.

   ```
   mChosenStorageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < Uri > () {
       @Override public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
           mDownloadUrl = uri.toString();
           // Send datas to RTDB
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: thank you very much for reply. I tried using both ways you're describing, but I haven't got the solution. The 1-st way gave me something like com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzh@96b2841. The second way is pushing the Url to Database, right. But it's pushing it to a separate object in the DB what I don't need. Hope I understood you correctly.